# fork() usage not getting the correct output

Tags: c, fork

I am using the following code for a fork execution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    int pid;
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        printf("\n child 1");
        pid=fork();
        if (pid==0)
           printf("\n child 2");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output I assume should be 
child1
child2

Instead I am getting

child1
child2 child1

Cannot understand the fork behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flush stdout:

```
printf( "\n child 1" )
fflush( stdout );
```

Comment: Also note that the issue would never have arisen had OP not been practicing the ridiculous "put your \n's at the beginning of the message" anti-pattern.

Comment: An interesting side-effect of line buffering, then?

Answer (score 3):

If you have written data to any stdio `FILE` before calling `fork` and intend to use the same `FILE` after `fork`, you **must** call `fflush` on that `FILE` before calling `fork`. Failure to do so results in **undefined behavior**.

See here for the formal requirements:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01

Specifically,

> Note that after a fork(), two handles exist where one existed before. The application shall ensure that, if both handles can ever be accessed, they are both in a state where the other could become the active handle first. The application shall prepare for a fork() exactly as if it were a change of active handle. (If the only action performed by one of the processes is one of the exec functions or _exit() (not exit()), the handle is never accessed in that process.)